# Reflecting code inside of Android applications from hosting servers without new build

Tags: java, android, dart

Greetings of the day

I know you have a busy schedule. Would you like to give me your 10 to 20 minutes for a discussion. I have a doubt and did some google search for this. There are some information but those are not much clear.
I am sure that if this doubt resolved and we found the solution to achieve the objective. It will help us for each and every project. It can be a time taking solution but only required once to get the line.

Doubt :- Do we can make an application which hit an url and take a response and according response performe some commands to write and read or modify the file itself.

In Java or other language.

In short without building new generated file code can reflect as like in web it happen.

Example :- we write and save the code file in web development at host location. Browser hit the url and show the output as it is newly writen code.
If we have added a new button in our website it reflects after saving the file.

Same thing I wanted to perform in Java and Android or dart.

Issue to solve:- the review time taken by play store. And for each update we need to build new apk each time.

Comment: If you plan on releasing on Google Play-  this is against their terms of service.  It gets around the entire point of the play store review-  they want to ensure that the version of the code they approve is the version run, because a future version can have any type of malware and they wouldn't be able to catch it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.